# implementing CORS in API for native app

Tags: cors, icenium

I'm using Icenium to develop a native app. Currently just built one sample hybrid application using icenium (www.icenium.com) to call API using jQuery ajax, but still getting some errors saying "Possible CORS error!" in Icenium.

I've read through how I can implement CORS headers to allow cross domain ajax, however seems it is still not working in my native app built through icenium.

Here's my response header:

```
Content-Length: 76 
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Language: en 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Status_code: 200
Vary: Accept-Language, Cookie 
Allow: GET, POST 
Date: Sun, 01 Dec 2013 07:41:33 GMT 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Content-Type: application/json 
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

Does any one see any problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Problem was the API server for testing didn't had valid SSL cert, so was failing. I changed the request to http and solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using Icenium Mist (the browser-based IDE)? If so, due to the limitations of the simulator in the browser, you'll run into this problem. If possible, try the Windows IDE (Graphite) or the Visual Studio extension. More info here: http://docs.icenium.com/testing-your-app/running-apps-in-simulator/device-simulator

Comment: I get that error message fro Mist. But what about from the build on native application?

Comment: I know that the work around is to test on the app on the device. But still doesnt work.

Comment: You may have better luck trying to post something on the Icenium forums: http://www.icenium.com/resources/forums

Comment: Try submitting a support request, those are responded to within a day or so easily!